# Save files using Storage::put and XMLHttpRequest in Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, xmlhttprequest, laravel-5.3

I am trying send file using DRAG & DROP with `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
$images = $_FILES['images'];
```

when I use foreach:

```
foreach($images["name"] as $file => $name)
```

and

```
move_uploaded_file($images["tmp_name"][$file], $images_dir . $name
```

it works fine but I'd like to use

```
Storage::put
```

but it not works

I have:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

and in `filesystems.php`

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

When I point mouse cursor to 'put' in my PHPStorm IDE `"Method 'put' not found in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage"`

class Storage extends Facade but in Facade there is no 'put' method too. What is wrong with `Storage` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage` just say `use Storage`

Then ignore any IDE errors and proceed to see whether its working. Laravel uses magic methods and many other architectural patterns. Not all IDEs can evaluate its code properly so just ignore the IDE errors

Avoid using $_FILES as well. Use the following:

```
$files = $request->input('images');
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
    if ($request->hasFile('images.' . $key)) {
        $file = $request->file('images.' . $key);
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::put($filename, file_get_contents($file));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but I cant still resolve problem Storage::put. I think the problem may be what is in $_FILE using as file name from XMLHttpRequest becouse when I am using data from Reguest recieved from form -> input type"file" works fine.